# using webmock with cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I am using webmock and it is not working for cucumber tests

In my Gemfile

```
  gem 'vcr'
  gem 'webmock'
```

And in my features/support.env.rb, I have

```
require 'webmock/cucumber'
WebMock.allow_net_connect!
```

When I run my cucumber tests I am getting this error.

```
    Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request:
 GET http://127.0.0.1:9887/__identify__ with headers
 {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}
```

Am I doing anything wrong or is sth missing?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

First off, if you're using VCR, you don't need to configure webmock with the `require 'webmock/cucumber'` line and the `WebMock.allow_net_connect!` line.  VCR takes care of any necessary WebMock configuration for you.

The request that is triggering the error looks like it's coming from Capybara.  When you use one of the javascript drivers, capybara boots your app using a simple rack server, and then polls the special `__identify__` path so it knows when it has finished booting.

VCR includes support for ignoring localhost requests so that it won't interfere with this.  The [relish docs](http://relishapp.com/myronmarston/vcr/v/1-10-0/dir/configuration/ignore-localhost) have the full story but the short version is that you need to add VCR configuration like this:

```
VCR.config do |c|
  c.ignore_localhost = true
end
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, at least not within a Spork.prefork block.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same error though do not use VCR. I was able to resolve this by adding:

```
require 'webmock/cucumber'
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(:allow_localhost => true)
```

to my env.rb file.

Comment: The `disable_net_connect!` method call with the `:allow_localhost` option is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Lovely and simplest solution, which I did not get even on watir/cucumber sites

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on [Myron Marston's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6120205/446954). If you need to keep localhost for something else, such as a Rack App, that you might want VCR to capture request for, you will need to create a custom matcher rather than ignore all localhost requests.

```ruby
require 'vcr'

VCR.configure do |c|
  c.hook_into :webmock
  c.ignore_localhost = false

  c.ignore_request do |request|
    localhost_has_identify?(request)
  end
end


private
def localhost_has_identify?(request)
  if(request.uri =~ /127.0.0.1:\d{5}\/__identify__/)
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

If you use both RSpec and Cucumber, you might need to create two config files for WebMock (when using with VCR):

```
# spec/support/webmock.rb
# Config for RSpec
require 'webmock/rspec'
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)

# features/support/webmock.rb
# Config for Cucumber
require 'webmock/cucumber'
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
```

Documenting this here for people to find when googling for `__identify__`. Errors look like...

```
Real HTTP connections are disabled.
Unregistered request: GET http://127.0.0.1:59005/__identify__
```