# Cucumber, VCR gem and chrome driver not working together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I'm trying to run cucumber using VCR gem, chrome driver, and webmock but it's not working. One problem is that **none** of the requests are getting recorded. I do have VCR set to `ignore_localhost` which I believe is needed due to javascript as explained in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6120205/600953).

**But why doesn't my step request to visit a url (say `www.test.com`) get recorded?** I see the chrome browser loading up and the address in the URL so I know the cucumber step is going there.

If i turn off `ignore_localhost` then I see some recordings but the uri's are all `127.0.0.1`. The uri I'd expect is showing up in `body: string` instead of the `uri`. **Why is this happening?**

```
request:
  method: post
  uri: http://127.0.0.1:9592/session/87bb12aa8b5b1230399b98bcc7d0ba11/url
  body:
    encoding: US-ASCII
    string: ! '{"url":"http://www.test.com"}'
  headers:
    Accept:
    - application/json
    Content-Type:
    - application/json; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length:
    - '46'
    User-Agent:
    - Ruby
```

Incase it helps, here's my VCR config

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'features/support/vcr_cassettes'
  c.hook_into :webmock
  c.ignore_localhost = true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, set your configuration like this:

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'features/support/vcr_cassettes'
  c.hook_into :webmock
  c.ignore_localhost = true
  c.allow_http_connections_when_no_cassette = false
end
```

With the last option you tell VCR that no real http requests are allowed, without a cassette. Now run your tests. I bet that it'll throw an error! Now you have to tell VCR when to use which cassette. Have a look at the cucumber helpers for VCR here https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-4-0/docs/test-frameworks/usage-with-cucumber

VCR includes some helpers for other testing frameworks too https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-4-0/docs/test-frameworks